# how to redirect page after sending javascript form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello I have this form that uses js that after you click the the approve button it will change the button to success and send the data,  it will run a php script to update the database. That part is working however I would like to reload the page after the information is sent but everything i've tried will not work. Here is what i currently have.

js

```
$("#approvePirep").on("click", function() {
var a = $(this).data("ppm"), n = $(this).data("pid"), s = $(this).data("pirep-id"), e = $(this);
    $.ajax("includes/ajax/noc/acceptpirep.php?pid=" + n + "&ppm=" + a + "&pirepid=" + s).done(function(a) {
        "1" == a ? e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success") : e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
    }).fail(function() {
        e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
    });
 window.location.href = "https://virtualua.org/ams/index.php?page=noc";
})
```

php of the information being sent

```
<?php
require("checkstaff.php");
require("../../logaction.php");

function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit = "N") {
    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad((float)$lat1)) * sin(deg2rad((float)$lat2)) + cos(deg2rad((float)$lat1)) * cos(deg2rad((float)$lat2)) * cos(deg2rad((float)$theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    return ($miles * 0.8684);
}

function getAirportValue($icao, $col) {
  global $pdo;

  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT $col FROM airports WHERE icao = ?");
  $query->execute([$icao]);
  return $query->fetchColumn();
}

function ppm($point_value) {
  if ($point_value < "25000") {
    $ppm = 1;
  }
  if ($point_value >= "25000" AND $point_value < "49999") {
    $ppm = 3;
  }
  if ($point_value >= "50000" AND $point_value < "99999") {
    $ppm = 5;
  }
  if ($point_value >= "100000" AND $point_value < "149999") {
    $ppm = 8;
  }
  if ($point_value >= "150000") {
    $ppm = 10;
  }
  return $ppm;
}

function calcPoints($dep, $arr) {

  $dep_lat = getAirportValue($dep, "latitude");
  $dep_lon = getAirportValue($dep, "longitude");
  $arr_lat = getAirportValue($arr, "latitude");
  $arr_lon = getAirportValue($arr, "longitude");

  $pointpermile = ppm($_GET['ppm']);

  $distance = distance($dep_lat, $dep_lon, $arr_lat, $arr_lon, "n");

  return round($distance * $pointpermile);
}

if(isStaff() == true) {
  if(isset($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['pirepid']) {
    $pinfo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pireps WHERE id = ?");
    $pinfo->execute([$_GET['pirepid']]);
    $pinfo = $pinfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pireps SET status = 1 WHERE id = ?")->execute([$_GET['pirepid']]);
    $query1 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pilots SET hours = hours + ?, points = points + ?, last_airport = ?, flights = flights + 1, lastpirep = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()  WHERE id = ?")->execute([$pinfo['time'], calcPoints($pinfo['dep'], $pinfo['arr']), $pinfo['arr'], $_GET['pid']]);

    logAction($_GET['pid'], "Accepted PIREP #".$_GET['pirepid']);

    echo 1;
  } else {
    echo 0;
  }
} else {
  echo 0;
}

?>
```

and the html and php of the modal that this form is in

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pirep<?= $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pirep<?= $row['id']; ?>Label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="pirep<?= $row['id']; ?>Label">Viewing PIREP #<?= $row['id']; ?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Pilot:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= $userInfo['login']." - ".$userInfo['fname']." ".$userInfo['lname']." (".$userInfo['rank'].")"; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Flight:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= $row['fnum']." (".$row['dep']." - ".$row['arr'].")"; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Date:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= date('m/d/Y', $row['date']); ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Time:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= $row['time']; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Route:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= $row['route']; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Aircraft:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= $row['ac']; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">A/C Code:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= $row['ac_code']; ?>">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="updatePirepAC" data-pid="<?= $row['pid']; ?>" data-pirep-id="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><i class="material-icons">check</i></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Landing Rate:</div>
        <div class="col-md-8"><?= $row['landingrate']; ?> FPM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">Pilot Comments:</div>
        <?php
          if (strpos($row['comments'], "Manual CCS Report") !== false){
              echo  "<div class='col-md-8'><a href='" . substr($row['comments'], 0, strpos($row['comments'],"|")) . "' target='_blank'>".$row['comments'] . "</a></div>";
          } else {
              echo  "<div class='col-md-8'>" . $row['comments'] . "</div>";
          }
        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="row m-2">
          <div class="col-md-4">System Comments:</div>
          <div class="col-md-8"><?= $row['acomments']; ?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="rejectPirep" data-pid="<?= $row['pid']; ?>" data-pirep-id="<?= $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-animation="false" title="Reject"><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="approvePirep" id="approvePirep" data-pid="<?= $row['pid']; ?>" data-pirep-id="<?= $row['id']; ?>" data-ppm="<?= $userInfo['points']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-animation="false" title="Accept"><i class="material-icons">check</i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `but everything i've tried will not work` what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: `location = 'yourURLHere.php'`.

Comment: @void I'm not getting any error. the button to approve turns green after clicking the the php is execute to update the database, but i can not get it to reload the page after. even after moving window.location code after the done function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed window.location.href to location.href and it refreshes the page correctly, I did try location.reload as suggested it did work however it was reloading the page and the next time a new modal was opened to accept another pirep it would bring in some but not all data from the last form, but was fixed by using my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your JS:

```
window.location.href = "https://virtualua.org/ams/index.php?page=noc";
```

and relocate it inside `.done()` ajax call.

You should re-direct the page after you have received a reply from `ajax`..

```
$.ajax("includes/ajax/noc/acceptpirep.php?pid=" + n + "&ppm=" + a + "&pirepid=" + s).done(function(a) {
        "1" == a ? e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success") : e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");

        window.location.href = "https://virtualua.org/ams/index.php? page=noc";   //here
    }).fail(function() {
        e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
    });
```

Comment: did that and still no redirect

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because your code is executing asynchronously & you are not aware of that. Just move your reload code inside the success/error (as you need) callback like this-

```
$("#approvePirep").on("click", function() {
var a = $(this).data("ppm"), n = $(this).data("pid"), s = $(this).data("pirep-id"), e = $(this);
    $.ajax("includes/ajax/noc/acceptpirep.php?pid=" + n + "&ppm=" + a + "&pirepid=" + s).done(function(a) {
        "1" == a ? e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-success") : e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
        // here
        window.location.href = "https://virtualua.org/ams/index.php?page=noc";
    }).fail(function() {
        e.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
    });
})
```

Comment: have you tried this - `location.reload();` to reload?